# Strongly edge-guarding a 3d triangulation

Tags: graph-theory, cg.comp-geom, upper-bounds, delaunay-triangulation

Let $T$ be a planar triangulation.  It is known that one can guard the faces of $T$ using at most $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor$ edge-guards ([Worst-case-optimal algorithms for guarding planar graphs and polyhedral surfaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0925-7721%2803%2900027-0)). I am trying to obtain a similar upper bound for an extension of this problem, as follows.

Now, let $T$ be a three-dimensional triangulation (a tetrahedralization), and let $S$ be a subset of its edges.  We say that $S$ **strongly guards** $T$ if, for every tetrahedron in $T$, one of the six edges of that tetrahedron lies in $S$.  **Is there a known nontrivial upper bound for the number of edges required to strongly guard all tetrahedra of a tetrahedralization?**

Obviously, this problem can be solved via *edge-coloring with no monochromatic tetrahedra*. Is there any upper bound on the edge chromatic number for three-dimensional triangulations better than $\Delta + 1$? Maybe the assumption that $T$ is a Delaunay triangulation can conduct to a probabilistic bound.

Comment: I clarified the definition of "guard", but I may have it wrong.  In the art-gallery literature, an edge in a 2d triangulation usually guards every triangle that contains _at least one endpoint_ of that edge.  In particular, this is the definition used in the paper you cite.

Comment: A few more questions: (1) Do you mean a triangulation of a convex polytope in $R^3$, of an arbitrary genus-zero polyhedron in $R^3$, of an arbitrary polyhedron in $R^3$, of an arbitrary topological ball, or of an arbitrary 3-manifold?  [The paper you cite considers only planar triangulations.]  (2) Do you want upper bounds in terms of the number of vertices or the number of edges?  [Even if you consider only Delaunay triangulations, an $n$-vertex triangulation can have $\Omega(n^2)$ edges.]

Comment: @JɛﬀE, your definition of "guard" is exactly what I meant. The word "triangulation" stands for _triangulation of a finite point set $X \subset \mathbf{R}^3$_ or, equivalently, _triangulation of a convex polytope in $\mathbf{R}^3$_, as you suggested.

Comment: I am interested in an upper bound in terms of the _number of edges_. A 3D Delaunay triangulation can have $\Omega(n^2)$ edges in the worst case, but if we consider points distributed uniformly at random inside the 3-ball there will be an expected linear number of them, right? ([Higher-dimensional Voronoi diagrams in expected linear time](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/73833.73869))

Comment: Sure.  Moreover, the expected degree of any edge in the Delaunay triangulation of random points is also constant; you can probably find the precise value in [Okabe, Boots, Sugihara, and Chiu](http://www.amazon.com/Spatial-Tessellations-Applications-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471986356).  So for some explicit constant $c$, the expected number of necessary edge guards is at most $n/c$.  But that's kind of boring, isn't it?

Comment: @JɛﬀE, I am just looking for that $c$, regardless of the number of edges $e$. Obviously, the following holds for any triangulation: $1 \le c \le e$. A triangulation consisting of a "fan" of tetrahedra ilustrates the lower bound. For a worst-case Delaunay triangulation of $2n$ points (as ilustrated in Fig. 13.2 of [Algorithmic geometry](http://amzn.com/0521565294)), there are $n^2 + 2(n-1)$ edges. In this case, it suffices to select $(n - 1)$ edges for the guarding set. Because $2n \ge 4$, it follows that $c = (n^2 + 2(n - 1))/(n-1) \le 2n + 2$. Any ideas for "random" Delaunay triangulations?